# Setting a timeout on Google Calendar API requests?

Tags: c#, .net, google-calendar-api, connection-timeout

I have written a program in C# using the Google Calendar API via the .NET nuget packages. One of my users is having an issue where the `Events.List` request seems to be timing-out after 100 seconds (throwing a `TaskCanceledException`). I had the user test the same request via the Google API explorer ([link here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/events/m/calendar/v3/calendar.events.list?calendarId=onuralparslan%2540gmail.com&maxResults=1&orderBy=startTime&q=http%253A%252F%252Fmilky.geocities.jp%252Fkyotonosato%252F&showDeleted=false&singleEvents=true&_h=3&)) and they got error 503:

```
503
{
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 503,
  "message": "Backend Error"
}
}
```

Google seems to [recommend exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors) in this case, but I am not sure if that will work since this happens every single time the user clicks this particular button. Is there a way to increase the timeout limit for Google Calendar API requests?

Comment: there is a library called Polly which may be of use in this situation - http://www.thepollyproject.org/